# Phonegap, jQueryMobile And Web service

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I created a native Android app using the Android SDK and java packages, using a ASP.Net Web service created by me, and it works fine. But now I want to make this cross-platform. I heard that Phonegap and jQuery Mobile will help with this, but I am still a bit confused.

1. Is it necessary to host the HTML file that uses Javascript to work properly?
   OR
2. Can I include the HTML and js file in my application and call the web service methods?

Can somebody please guide me?

MY Demo Code is

JAVA SCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery-1.7.2.min"></script>
 <script src="jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"/></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" src="jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript">


function onDeviceReady() {}
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function LoginButton_onclick() {
    $.ajax({
type: "POST",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
    url:    "http://182.72.192.18/webservicedemo/service.asmx/HelloWorld",
    data: '{}',
    success: function(msg) {
   jsonArray = $.parseJSON(msg.d);
    var $ul = $( '<ul id="details">' );
    for(i=0; i < jsonArray.length; i++)
    {
  $("#details").append('<li id="'+i+'" name="head" >'+jsonArray[i].name+'</li>' );
} $('#details').listview('refresh');
    },
    error: function(msg) {
         alert("Error");
    }
});

</script>
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="Page1">
<h1>DEMO PAGE</h1>

<div id="DEMO"> 
<input id="LoginButton" type="button" value="GET DATA" onclick="LoginButton_onclick()" /></div>

<div id="divList" data-role="content">
<ul id="details" data-role="listview" data-inset="true"></ul>
</div>

</div>     
</body>
```

and my ASP.NET Web Service is

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService{
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
public Service () {}

[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string HelloWorld() {

    List<clsDetails> deailsList = new List<clsDetails>{
    new clsDetails(1,"BOY","SCHOOL"),
    new clsDetails(2,"GIRL","COLLEGE"),
    new clsDetails(3,"MAN","OFFICE")};

    string detail = serializer.Serialize(deailsList);
    return detail;
}
}
```

if i host the html file along with my web-service it provide me result .
but when i try to call using a local html file from android app it fails. 
i can't figure out what went wrong.

Can anyone tell me what went wrong here?
Look here is the response i get from web-service and i parse that to JSON

[image: HTML HOSTED ALONG WITH WEBSERVICE]

phonegap.xml

```
<phonegap>  
<access origin="http://182.72.192.18" /> 
</phonegap>
```

Comment: Did you look at the phonegap web site? It's pretty well documented.

Comment: @jiggy I doesn't mean it is a website .. i am asking that can phone-gap can used to call dynamic web services . what is the way to do it?

Comment: And I meant go [phonegap.com](http://phonegap.com/developer) and read the docs before you ask really basic questions. Try googling your questions before you post.

Comment: @jiggy my code is here would u help me to sort out what went wrong. i am novice in web-technology and js . i failed to find what went wrong

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use a local html and get the server data using XHR calls to your webservice, and then show the data of your webservice in your html.

Edit after seeing the code:

The problem is the url. You can't use localhost, because if you test on a device, localhost is the device, and the device doesn't have the webservice, you have to use the local iP of your machine. http://192.168.1.XXX:1000/WebSite2/Service.asmx/HelloWorld

Edit 2:
I just tested your code and got it working for me, just change this.
The jsonArray[i].Result didn't work for me, it return undefined, but you can access to every attribute of the json object, in the example I used the name.
And put the refresh outside the for, you only have to refresh when you finish, not every time, and put the `;` at the end.

```
for(i=0; i < jsonArray.length; i++)
    {
  $("#details").append('<li id="'+i+'" name="head" >'+jsonArray[i].name+'</li>' );

}
$('#details').listview('refresh');
```

If it still don't work, check if you whitelisted the domain [phonegap whitelist guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html)

Full working code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>DEMO</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <title>DEMO</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

            function LoginButton_onclick() {
                $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                       dataType: "json",
                       url:    "http://182.72.192.18/webservicedemo/service.asmx/HelloWorld",
                       data: '{}',
                       success: function(msg) {
                       jsonArray = $.parseJSON(msg.d);
                       var $ul = $( '<ul id="details">' );
                       for(i=0; i < jsonArray.length; i++)
                       {
                       $("#details").append('<li id="'+i+'" name="head" >'+jsonArray[i].name+'</li>' );
                       }
                       $('#details').listview('refresh');
                       },
                       error: function(msg) {
                       alert("Error");
                       }
                       });

            }


            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div data-role="page" id="Page1">
                <h1>DEMO PAGE</h1>

                <div id="DEMO">
                    <input id="LoginButton" type="button" value="GET DATA" onclick="LoginButton_onclick()" /></div>

                <div id="divList" data-role="content">
                    <ul id="details" data-role="listview" data-inset="true"></ul>
                </div>

            </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: actually my problem is I host the html with web-service and works fine and i got the output result also to html file. but when i use this as local html file for my android app it doesn't work. i can't figure out what was wrong?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the code, but if you plan to make the app for iOS too, it's advisable to use a xml/json webservice instead a html one. Make sure you use the full url to your webservice (http://www.example.com/yourwebservice) and make sure you don't use any server language in your local html (it's a common mistake using php in the local html, but phonegap can't execute php)

Comment: i'm not using php in my html(i don't know PHP) anyway thanks for the information

Comment: I thought by running that port we can access data through it..its my mistake .. i will check your edited answer and inform about the results

Comment: http://182.72.192.18/webservicedemo/service.asmx/HelloWorld this is my hosted service url.. still it is not working for me..

Comment: The webservice is returning a xml with json inside, try to return just json. Does the console shows any error? which version of phonegap are you using? did you whitelist the url you want to access?

Comment: well i am using parseJSON to parse the response to json format and returns me correct json format...i am posting an image here with my response.. i just want to know what is the failure happening when i call it locally..are you telling me that this is because of my response ...

Comment: check my last edit, your code works for me with a little change.

Comment: did my service work for you? actually i had edited phonegap.xml to whitelist my domain..its also included here.. still i cant figure our what is wrong here.

Comment: i don't know where it fails..  i mean it goes to the error part of ajax call and show me the custom error alert(please refer my script part)...my console doesn't show any error...I tried it .. but still not working... if you don't mind can u post the working code of your's

Comment: i had tried the different overloads for white listing the domain still ..i can't get the result...

Comment: I just updated the full working code I used, so, if you paste that code into your index.html replacing all the code you have, and it still doesn't work, it isn't a code problem, is configuration problem.

Comment: yes as you said .. i used your code.. i think its configuration problem.. is there any error in my domain white-listing .. i checked my manifest xml file all permissions (i think internet permission is sufficient i had provided that along with other permissions) are given there... what can be the problem here ?

Comment: Which version of phonegap are you using? Because now phonegap is called cordova, so you configure the whitelist on cordova.xml, not on phonegap.xml. The page was shown correctly with my code? Because if the whitelist is wrong it shouldn't load the css and js of my code. Try with this for the whitelist <access origin="*" />

Answer (score 3):

The problem that you have it's that you can't access your webservice from your mobile device, only when you run your program with your computer's emulator. 
You must do this:

- Have your webservice in a server, not in localhost.
- Edit res/xml/cordova.xml for no crossdomain problems.

  ```
  <!-- <access origin="https://example.com" /> allow any secure requests to example.com -->
  <!-- <access origin="https://example.com" subdomains="true" /> such as above, but including subdomains, such as www -->
  <!-- <access origin=".*"/> Allow all domains, suggested development use only -->
  ```

With these steps your program will function perfectly.

**Edit**

I've seen that the type you're returning in your WS is not in JSON style. Your response is something between XML and JSON. When you get the correct return value of the WebMethod everything will go OK.

You must use last version of Cordova and jQM. See that your jQM CSS and JS don't match in versions.

Comment: check my java-script i hosted my service and its still showing error

Comment: i had posted my response in html page can you have look on it

Comment: not sure why if this answered the OP but it def fixed my issues, thanks mram

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the HTML file showing the data + JS calling the web service with your app. Through data injection (e.g. JSON or XML through XHR calls), you can pull the data from your web service. This means that your web service should output the requested data in JSON or XML so that your HTML + JS will be able to process and show the data from your web service. You can do this with PhoneGap SDK or even PhoneGap Build.

A simple example that I personally like can be found here: http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/10/sample-application-with-jquery-mobile-and-phonegap/. Instead of ASP.NET, it works with PHP / MySQL, but the concept is basically the same, I would think.

Comment: i provided my html ,js and web-service code but the problem i am facing is if i host the html file along with my web-service it provide me result . but when i try to call using a local html file from android app it fails. i can't figure out what went wrong..

Comment: my code is working if i host along with my web-service but when i use it locally it won't .. i mean it goes to the error part of ajax call and show me the custom error alert(please refer my script part)... i don't know where it fails.. my console doesn't show any error

Answer (score 2):

This is a good example I found http://www.idesigncity.co.uk/how-to-fetch-json-data-from-phonegap
Usually JSON or XML call will be your answer. Download the zip in there