# PhoneGap, jQueryMobile, JSON, ASP.NET WebService ASMX

Tags: json, web-services, cordova, asmx

I'm creating a mobile app for/with PhoneGap. I am trying to load external data through a ASP.NET Web Service created it by myself. The Web Service works correct when I run the local with the Ripple Emulator and with the url set to the local Web Service. The moment I change the url to the online version, so cross-platform, it doesn't wor anymore in my local Ripple Emulator, I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token e
  at Object.parse (native)
  at IncomingMessage.module.exports (/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/json.js:76:27)
  at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:93:17)
  at HTTPParser.parserOnMessageComplete [as onMessageComplete] (http.js:149:23)
  at Socket.socket.ondata (http.js:1825:22)
  at TCP.onread (net.js:404:27)"
```

I read a lot of possible solutions online but I cannot seem to fix the problem. After reading [Phonegap, jQueryMobile And Web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323747/phonegap-jquerymobile-and-web-service) I thought it was something simple and it should work without the solution of JSONP, Proxies, HttpHandlers, and such.

Below I added some of my code that should be relevant:

**HTML/JAVASCRIPT**

```
    function onBodyLoad() {
        // Add the PhoneGap deviceready event listener
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Test the function
        login();
    }

    function login() {
        try {
            // Validate credentials
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'http://login.multiviewer.nl/Mobile.asmx/ValidateCredentials',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: '{ username: "x", password: "y", browser: "", title: "", ipAddress: "" }',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (object) {
                    alert("success");
                },
                error: function (em, msg) {
                    alert("function error");
                }
            });
        }
        catch (err) {
            alert("catch error");
        }
    }

//-->
</script>
```

**ASP.NET Web Service ASMX**

```
namespace Web.Core.WebServices
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    [ScriptService]
    public class Mobile : WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public string ValidateCredentials(string username, string password, string browser, string title, string ipAddress)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> keyValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            keyValues.Add("Something", "Ok");
            JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            return jss.Serialize(keyValues);
        }
    }
}
```

**PHONEGAP**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.multiviewer.app" version="1.0.1" versionCode="1">

  <!-- General app settings -->
  <name>App name</name>
  <description>App description</description>
  <author href="http://www.rhainesoft.nl/" email="info@rhainesoft.nl">RhaineSoft</author>

  <!-- App icon -->
  <icon src="images/icon.jpg" />

  <!-- Features used, rights needed at installing -->
  <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
  <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
  <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />

  <!-- Expose access to all URIs, including the file and http protocols -->
  <access origin=".*"/>

  <!-- Content -->
  <content src="index.html" />

</widget>
```

I appreciate any help to fix this problem with me. If you have any questions or if I missed something please let me know.